# Exclude or Include certain profile lines during a tmux session start

Tags: linux, bash, user-profile, bashrc, tmux

In my `.bash_profile`, I have a line to start tmux *only* if it is present on the system with:

```
[ -z $TMUX ] && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

In a similar vein, I would like to skip or include certain lines:

• Have certain lines in my .bash_profile that only run during a tmux session start.

• Have certain lines in my .bash_profile that do *not* run during a tmux session start.

What would the syntax be to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because -z will return **true** if the environment variable have an empty value.
So you have to use instead  :

```
[ ! -z $TMUX ] && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

Where the exclamation **(!)** mark negate the conditional test.